# Using compass in a grunt build is it possible to compile a different set of sass files depending on if running compass:server vs compass:dist?

Tags: gruntjs, font-awesome, grunt-contrib-copy

Basically, I want to have a partial called _variables.scss for production and _variables-test.scss for testing.  I need to set a path variable for font-awesome that will be different in production than when simply testing using "grunt serve" because the production app will have an extra path element.  So for production the path would be "/distribution/fonts" where testing would simply be "/fonts".

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) you can define different font folders by setting `fontDir` in a task config.